# PySide.phonon and media formats such as mp4,flv,mkv,eg

Tags: pyside

I am absolutely a pyside newbie ，and want to use PySide.phonon to write a mediaplayer .my question is ：can the media player support media formats such as mp4,flv,mkv,eg ?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to answer this question is to either try to play the kind of files you're interested in, or check the list of supported mimetypes.

Here's a demo video player that should allow you to do that:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide.phonon import Phonon

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Video Player')
        self.media = Phonon.MediaObject(self)
        self.video = Phonon.VideoWidget(self)
        self.video.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
        self.audio = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory, self)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.audio)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.video)
        self.buttonChoose = QtGui.QPushButton('Choose File', self)
        self.buttonMimes = QtGui.QPushButton('Show Mimetypes', self)
        self.slider = Phonon.VolumeSlider(self)
        self.slider.setAudioOutput(self.audio)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.video, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonChoose, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonMimes, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.media.stateChanged.connect(self.handleStateChanged)
        self.buttonChoose.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonChoose)
        self.buttonMimes.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonMimes)

    def handleButtonChoose(self):
        if self.media.state() == Phonon.PlayingState:
            self.media.stop()
        else:
            dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
            dialog.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
            if dialog.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
                path = dialog.selectedFiles()[0]
                self.media.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(path))
                self.media.play()
            dialog.deleteLater()

    def handleButtonMimes(self):
        dialog = MimeDialog(self)
        dialog.exec_()

    def handleStateChanged(self, newstate, oldstate):
        if newstate == Phonon.PlayingState:
            self.buttonChoose.setText('Stop')
        elif (newstate != Phonon.LoadingState and
              newstate != Phonon.BufferingState):
            self.buttonChoose.setText('Choose File')
            if newstate == Phonon.ErrorState:
                source = self.media.currentSource().fileName()
                print ('ERROR: could not play: %s' % source)
                print ('  %s' % self.media.errorString())

class MimeDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setWindowTitle('Mimetypes')
        listbox = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        listbox.setSortingEnabled(True)
        backend = Phonon.BackendCapabilities
        listbox.addItems(backend.availableMimeTypes())
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(listbox)
        self.resize(300, 500)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('Phonon Player')
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: when I run your program ,it surely generated a window Application ,but I guess it can't used to play videos .

Comment: @user1485853. Tested it again, and it works fine for me using either PySide or PyQt4 with an avi file on both Linux and WinXP. What files did you try to play, and what error messages do you see? Also, what platform are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Phonon is a wrapper library designed by KDE and adopted upsteam by Qt. The purpose of the library was to add portability to multimedia applications be abstracting away the details of the actual subsystem doing the media playback. On Windows, DirectShow plays the actual file; on OS X, QuickTime. On Linux, any number of media backend can play the file and they each have their own capabilities. Using the VLC backend, you can play pretty much everything under the sun on all platforms!

The result is that you, as an application developer, do not know what formats Phonon will be able to play on the computer that is running your code. Phonon, however, does provide some mechanisms for finding out what backend is being used and what its capabilities are. A good example is [this tutorial](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/phonon-capabilities.html) - albeit written in C++. Should be easy enough to understand and port to python.

Comment: how to use VLC backend as Phonon’s backend ?